# How to identify in table an input (check-box) followed by a text in <td>?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have to identify the path of check boxes in a row from a table using the text preceding them. The problem is that the text is inserted in a 'td'. 
The code is following:

<tr class="bz_row_even">
            <td align="center">
              <input type="checkbox" 
                name="email-0-10"
                value="1"

                   checked>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
              <input type="checkbox" 
                name="email-1-10"
                value="1"

                   checked>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <input type="checkbox" 
                name="email-2-10"
                value="1"

                   checked>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <input type="checkbox" 
                name="email-3-10"
                value="1"

                   checked>
            </td>

          <td>A new bug is created
          </td>
        </tr></code></pre>

In this example I have 4 check-boxer for a row. My query should be with a count to check the check-boxes in turn.
Could somebody help me with the path of check-boxes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Se-IDE, this becomes much easier. Here I just add the path to a list, but could use get_attribute or similar on the element that is been used.

```
paths = []
for checkbox in range(se.get_css_count("css=#bz_row_even input"):
    paths.append("css=#bz_row_even input[%d]" % checkbox)
```

Unless I completely misunderstand your question